# SFM lighting in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders, lighting, shadows

So I make thumbnails for youtubers, and one of my clients REALLY likes the look of SFM, I think that SFM is hard to work with and get anything done in. Is there anybody that knows how to make blenders lighting look like SFM's?[image: What I want to emulate]

Comment: What is SFM? Not everyone knows that

Comment: source film maker

Comment: This doesn't help as much. Please add some reference images/screenshots.

Comment: I fail to see what is special about the lighting in the image provided, the rim light? Please explain a bit more what it is you want. If possible, also provide a screenshots of a scene where you tried to do this yourself, or want to do it.

Comment: I understand how to do a rim light, but maybe something more like this updated image

Comment: Those two images are identical. What components of the image style are you trying to emulate? The model, the background, the lighting? Looks had textured to fake the lighting. Similar to this https://www.blendernation.com/2018/08/19/hand-painted-style-tutorial-old-cart/

Comment: I'm trying to emulate the lighting